# Modal form sheet on iPad transparent in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

I want to make a form sheet, presented modally, partially transparent, similar to how the volume meter or control center is partially transparent in iOS 7+.

I am programming using XCode 6.3.2, Swift 1.2, and it is for an iOS 8 platform (iPad).

I tried the following:

> Setting the ViewController's alpha value in Storyboard to 0.5

Background color result appears darker, but not see-through, text appears faint.

> Setting background color in Storyboard to "Clear Color"

Background color appears darker, did not notice fainter text.

> Setting background color to a color with 30% transparency

Similar to above.

> De - selecting `Clears Graphics Content`

No noticeable change to end result.

To clarify, I want a partially see-through modal view on iPad, not a darker background.

Is there any way to do this, in Swift or in the Storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rocket101, here's code I use to achieve a similar effect. It is in Objective C but you should be able to translate it easily.
During login I block my current view with "coverView" which presents a blurred logo. In your case you would not include the "backgroundImage".
Here is how I create the blurred effect.

```
  UIView *coverView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  coverView.frame = self.tabBarController.view.bounds;
  UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeBackgroundImage"];
  UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
  backgroundView.frame = self.tabBarController.view.bounds;
  UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
  blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];
  UIVisualEffectView *effectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
  effectView.frame = self.tabBarController.view.bounds;
  effectView.alpha = 0.8;
  [coverView addSubview:backgroundView];
  [coverView addSubview:effectView];
  [coverView sendSubviewToBack:effectView];
  [coverView sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];
  [theView addSubview:coverView];
```